# Decrease icon size on nexus 4

Tags: nexus-4, 4.4-kitkat

I got the ota update for kitkat and after that installed the android launcher ripped from nexus 5 rom. The result is that my icons look too big. Is there any way to decrease that or use a custom rom to change the size?

Comment: I strongly doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Just came across [KitKat Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kk.launcher&referrer=utm_source=xda&utm_medium=banner), a clone of the stock KK launcher with some mods. More info on their [XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2536422).

Jboi [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19201187/2554793):

> Unless you write you own Homescreen launcher or use an existing one
>   from Goolge Play, there's no way to resize icons.
>
> Well, no way does not mean its impossible:
>
> - As said, you can write [your own launcher as discussed in Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841686/how-to-make-a-launcher).
> - You can resize elements on the home screen, but these elements are [AppWidgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html). Since API level 14 they can be resized and user can - in
>     limits - change the size. But that are Widgets not Shortcuts for
>     launching icons.

Answer (score 0):

Use another launcher (for example, [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher)).